# use laravel + vue sanctum to apply authorization

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have a laravel + vue project and using sanctum for authentication, but I want to use authorization in my project too, I am looking for a solution similar to (spate laravel-permission) But I haven't found anything yet.

Can anyone help me to use authorization in my project please?

Answer (score 0):

Use middleware in your routes, or ACL-vue

Comment: I am working on ACL-vue but I don't know where the permits are coming from,if should I store them in the database?